# When does a gerund become a verb?

Tags: gerunds, parts-of-speech, participial-phrases, deverbal-nouns

My question is a follow-up to one in which I identified *stealing* and *killing* in a particular sentence as gerunds. Bill J commented to the effect that if objects followed these gerunds, the latter became verbs.

My questions are why and what form of the verb? For me the grammatical distinction between *“I dislike killing”* and *“I dislike killing sheep”* is simply that the gerund complement in the first becomes a gerund phrase complement in the second.

Comment: A gerund never becomes a verb. Whoever commented that is plain wrong. A gerund *always is* a verb form. And that verb form is "gerund".

Comment: What you have to remember is that in trad grammar, the central concept of gerund is that it is a word formed from a verb base which functions as or like or noun. But that is non-committal as to whether the word is in fact a verb or a noun. In order to establish which it is, you have to consider a number of things, for example complementation: transitive verbs take objects ("They were criticised for killing **the seals**"), whereas the corresponding nouns take of PPs (“They were criticised for the killing **of the seals**”). So "killing" is a verb in the 1st example and a noun in the 2nd

Comment: In your example "I dislike killing", the word "killing" is strictly ambiguous, but verb preferred, as "I dislike killing animals". Noun interpretation can be forced by adjectival premodification, as in "The occasional killing of badgers is justified" (note also the article "the" and the _of_ PP complement). As a verb, it is a participle, sometimes called a gerund-participle. In the verb interpretation, "killing" / "killing animals" would be analysed as gerund-participial clauses in complement function. As a noun, its function is 'head' of the NP.

Comment: I am going to use other sentences: I dislike golfing. I dislike playing golf.

Comment: I hope you're following all this !!!

Comment: Related http://english.stackexchange.com/q/66
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/13860
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/296621
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2625
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/95916
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/83675
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/170336
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/89966
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/154886
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31746
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/148670
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/301499
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77611
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/299578 &c.

Answer (score 3):

## *Running* as a noun, a verb, or an adjective

- **ᴛʟᴅʀ**: Not all *-ing* words in English are gerunds; some *-ing* words are not gerunds at all but rather nouns or adjectives. Therefore gerunds never “become” verbs because they never are **not** verbs. Gerunds are **always** verbs. However, gerund **phrases** can be used where a noun phrase is called for.

---

### A. *Running* as a deverbal noun

If an *-ing* word takes determiners and plural inflections and adjectives and adjectival prepositional phrases, it must be a noun not a verb.  These are deverbal nouns, not gerunds. They resist adverbs and verbal complements like direct or indirect object.

1. **The annual running of the bulls** during Pamplona’s San Fermín festival is fraught with peril.
2. **How many bull runnings** take place across Spain and Portugal every summer?

In sentence 1, *running* takes the determiner *the*, the adjective *annual*, and the prepositional phrase *of the bulls*.  It is clearly a noun, not a verb.

In sentence 2, *runnings* is the plural noun inflection, so it is again clearly a noun, not a verb.

So whether it’s this or that running or these or those runnings, these guys are always merely nouns. They are not gerunds because they are not verbs.  That’s why we call them ***deverbal*** nouns, because although they long ago began life as verbs, they’ve since been defrocked, so to speak, and so now are but common nouns only.

---

### B. *Running* as a verb: the gerund

In contrast, if an *-ing* word takes object complements and adverbs and adverbial prepositional phrases but resists those other things mentioned, then it must be a verb not a noun. These are the ones people call gerunds. A gerund is a verbal inflection used for a particular kind of non-finite verbal phrase; it acts mostly like a *to*-infinitive phrase does in this regard.

Like a *to*-infinitive, the **entire gerund phrase** serves as a noun phrase and so can serve as the subject of a clause or the object of a preposition, but the gerund itself is a verb form that does verb things.

3. **Running bulls** is harder work than herding cats.
4. The local custom of **wildly running unchaperoned bulls through the streets of Pamplona** has attracted countless tourists over the years, and injured not a few.
5. **Running scared** is sometimes preferable to standing still.

Notice how in sentence 3, the subject *running bulls* takes the singular verb *is*. That shows that *bulls* is not the subject and that *running* is not an adjective. *Running* is a verb and *bulls* that verb’s complement, and a gerund phrase is always considered singular for purposes of verbal concordance.

Sentence 4 demonstrates using the adverb *wildly* on *running*, again proving it a verb here.

Sentence 5 might mislead you into thinking *running* and *standing* are nouns because *scared* and *still* are adjectives. However, these are actually verbs whose complements are adjectives here.

---

### C. *Running* as a participial adjective

An *-ing* word can also act as a participial adjective. It acts as an adjective now, not as a verb.

6. **Loudly running bulls** are more perilous than quietly sleeping ones.
7. **Loud, running bulls** are more noticeable than quiet, sleeping ones.

Notice how in both 6 and 7, *running bulls* takes a plural verb, *are*. That shows you that *running* is merely an adjective here.  Notice how it precedes its noun just like any other normal adjective does in English.

We can use the adverb *loudly* to modify the adjective *running* as in 6.
But in 7 we use the adjective *loud* so it modifies not *running* but *bulls*; hence the comma.

---

### D. *Running* as a verb, revisited: the (present, active) participle

Lastly, an *-ing* word can be an actual participle, which like the gerund is a non-finite form of the verb. It can therefore serve as the head of a participle phrase. These participle phrases can modify either nouns or verbs, or serve as absolutes that apply to the entire sentence.

8. The person **running bulls through the streets** had best be fleet of foot.
9. I really tired myself out **running bulls through the streets** yesterday.
10. **Running bulls through the streets** yesterday, I really tired myself out.

In cases like example 8, this sort of right-branching modifying phrase of a noun can be seen as an instance of *whiz*-deletion, with something like *who is* considered to have gone missing.

- The person (who is) **running bulls through the streets** had best be fleet of foot.
- The person (who will be) **running bulls through the streets** had best be fleet of foot.
- The person (who goes) **running bulls through the streets** had best be fleet of foot.

In example 9, the participle phrase is an adverbial of manner; it modifies the verb phrase *tired myself how*.  In 10 it is an absolute participle phrase that applies to the entire sentence.

You can also think of these adverbials as being the secret objects of deleted prepositions:

11. I really tired myself out **(by) running bulls through the streets** yesterday.

---

## Oh no! *Caveat Lector*

Wait, did you see that? We just changed our analysis of *running* where it’s a verb acting adjectivally (so a participle) to a verb acting nominally (so a gerund).

Which one is it ***really***?

The answer is that it doesn’t matter. It’s just an *-ing* word.  The lessons here is that you shouldn’t get so hung up on applying Latin terms to English.
Some linguists call these words *gerund–participles* recognizing that the boundaries aren’t so clear cut in English the way they are in Latin.

Using Latin words like *gerund* and *participle* for English *-ing* words isn’t especially useful, and can be genuinely confusing. The various jobs that our *-ing* words do for us are easier to understand if you avoid confusing terminology from a borrowed language now long dead.

### Resolving Ambiguity

Your original question attempts to figure out whether an *-ing* word is acting like a noun or a verb.  You do have a point that there is ambiguity inherent in a phrase like:

12. I like **running bulls**. (*ambiguous*)

So sure, there is some level of ambiguity in example11 because you cannot tell whether the thing you like is the *running* itself (with *bulls* its verbal complement) or whether the thing you like is those *bulls* who just happen to be running.

Thing is, in practice it probably doesn’t matter much though which of these two understandings that ambiguous example 12 works out to being:

13. I like **running *the* bulls**. (*gerund phrase*)
14. I like ***the* running bulls**. (*participial adjective*)

In the rare case that it matters at all, inserting something to give away whether you have a noun or a verb as I have done here with *the*.  That’s only needed because *running bulls* is the object of *like*.  If that were the subject of the sentence then simple subject–verb agreement would tell you which it was, as previously demonstrated in sets A and B:

15. **Running bulls *is*** what I like to do.
16. **Running bulls *are*** what I like to avoid.

Comment: I think by posting such a huge answer, you risk losing your audience. I don't think the grammar of this is anywhere near as complicated as you're making out.

Comment: @BillJ Perhaps so. Shall we then promote [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346877/when-does-a-gerund-become-a-verb/346924?noredirect=1#comment802830_346877) into a Community Wiki answer, or [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346877/when-does-a-gerund-become-a-verb/346924?noredirect=1#comment802960_346889)? Or would you prefer to write your own?

Comment: You only have to look at the complementation to easily determine whether a word is a verb or a gerundial noun. It's not rocket science, you know!

Comment: @BillJ Meaning examples 12–16?

Answer (score 2):

What Bill J is talking about is that gerunds can take either adverbs and objects, or take adjectives, but not both.

So both the following are grammatical:

> I don't like needless killing.
>   I don't like killing sheep.

But you can't say:

> *I don't like needless killing sheep.

He clearly is classifying the gerund *killing* as a noun when it has an adjective, and as a verb when it takes an adverb or an object. But if you use this classification, there is no way to tell what part of speech *killing* is in *I don't like killing*. And you also have to change the rule that only nouns/noun phrases can be the subjects of sentences (e.g. *killing sheep is immoral*). This isn't how anybody else classifies gerunds.

You can get around this grammatical restriction by turning the adjective into an adverb:

> I don't like killing sheep needlessly,

or by inserting the preposition *of*:

> I don't like the needless killing of sheep.

Comment: Read my messages to the OP. What I said was that in "I dislike killing", the word "killing" is strictly speaking ambiguous, but verb preferred. If it's expanded to "I dislike killing animals", it is clearly a verb since it has a direct object. And I said that noun interpretation could be forced by adjectival premodification as in, say, "The occasional killing of badgers is justified".

Comment: @BillJ: Why is the verb be preferred? Who says? Does anybody else even use your classification?

Comment: Look, the important point here is that it is ambiguous. I notice that you didn't say what you consider the more salient interpretation of "killing" is in "I don't like killing" in your answer. My opinion is that verb is more likely that noun (cf. "I don't like to kill). What's yours?

Comment: Other determining factors are the occurrence of determiners. _The_ and comparable determiners combine with nouns, not verbs ("the killing of the birds", not *"the killing the birds"). And plural inflection: gerundial nouns can very often be inflected for plural ("These killings must stop", but not *"Killings the birds must stop).

Comment: It's still a noun either way. If you say *"Killing sheep is immoral"*, then *killing sheep* is the subject of the sentence, and subjects are nouns. Calling it a verb just confuses people.

Comment: There are other uses of the _-ing_ form as well. For instance, _anybody having the correct change_ is not transformed from *_anybody who is having the correct change_, because that doesn't allow progressive. In this one, _having_ is functionally equivalent to _with_ and might as well be called a preposition. The point is that identifying parts of speech is perhaps useful to satisfy a teacher in English class, but is not terribly helpful elsewhere.

Comment: If you're trying to teach the projection principle, you might as well use the official terminology. When I was teaching ESL, I always simply told them to look for clauses and then figure out how the clauses were used. Noun clauses are used as nouns, and gerund clauses can be and often are noun complement clauses.

Comment: @Peter Shor In trad grammar, that would be called a gerund simply because it is the subject of the clause, but function should not determine category.The range of expressions that occur as subject is quite varied: we don't want to call them all nouns. "Killing" in your example has the properties of indisputable verbs and hence must belong in that class.

Comment: Ah, a definitional problem. In most theories, "subject" is a particular noun phrase (or determiner phrase, if you go to a different church) which has certain syntactic characteristics. In relational theories, "subject" is a prime and not derived. "Gerund" is a term borrowed from Latin, which doesn't work well for English. What I call a gerund is an _-ing_ verb phrase in a noun complement clause; _-ing_ verb phrases in other clauses are called participles; any other _-ing_ words are either nouns or adjectives, again according to my usage.

Comment: @JohnLawler Your last sentence of your last comment immediately above is how I’ve always understood these. I’ve tried to incorporate all that in my answer, so if I’ve left anything out or gotten anything wrong, just let me know and I’ll fix it; or if you prefer, feel free to edit it yourself.

Comment: I suppose, thinking about it, that since _fuсking_ is both an _-ing_ word and an adverb in utterances like _You fuсking **gave** it to them??_, I ought to modify my last comment to say "other _-ing_ words are nouns, or adjectives, or adverbs". Another example of why identifying Parts Of Speech rarely gets you anywhere useful.

Comment: @John Lawler Whatever your personal opinions may be, some people find that having a good understanding of word categories as well as functions helpful in their understanding of the syntax of clauses. That's their choice, and I think it's unprofessional of you to repeatedly criticise what for them is an interesting aspect of grammar. Incidentally, I imagine the OP must despair of the way his question has been dealt with today.

Comment: Perhaps the OP has found that category definitions are not a simple matter, particularly for terms originated to describe a dead language 1500 years ago. There are a lot of categories, and textbooks and teachers vary wildly in their use, definition, and description. Names are cheap; descriptions are more valuable.

Comment: I don't buy that *killing* is a noun in the sentence *“Killing sheep is immoral”* all because we don’t want to confuse people taught that “subjects are nouns”. Just because sentences must have subjects and predicates doesn’t mean **all** subjects **must** be nouns; witness *“What they told is wrong”*, where the subject is the entire clause. That clause is no more a noun than the clause *killing sheep* is, but both can be subjects nonetheless. @JohnLawler In case you’ve any interest in answering it, I’ve again raised the matter in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/388099).

Comment: Any _-ing_ word that can take a direct object like _killing sheep_ is clearly a gerund, which is a verb form. Any  _-ing_ word that can take a definite article, like _the killing of the sheep_ is a noun.  Any _-ing_ word that appears outside an environment like these that distinguishes the two is both noun and verb, until its state tensor collapses.